# Powershell Prompt user for drive letter

Tags: powershell

I have a script that maps files in order to run VHDs.  But the drive letter can change when you run it from one machine to another.  How can I prompt the user which drive letter has the folder? or determine which drive letter has \Program Files\Microsoft Learning\20414\Drives\?

Actual Script Below:

```
Set-VHD -Path "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Learning\20414\Drives\20414B-LON-DC1\Virtual Hard Disks\20414B-LON-DC1.vhd” -ParentPath "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Learning\Base\Drives\MT12-WS12-LON-DC1-TMP.vhd”
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Read-Host` to prompt for user input. Like so,

`$vhdLocation = read-host "Enter path for VHD file"`

Instead of prompting user, you could list all the drives and check if the directory exists with `Get-PSDrive`, `Test-Path` and `Join-Path`. Like so,

```
get-psdrive | ? {
$_.root -match "[c-z]:\\" -and (test-path $(join-path $_.root "Program Files\Microsoft Learning\20414\Drives\"))
}
```

`$_.root -match "[c-z]:\\"` will match drive letters C: to Z:.

`$(join-path $_.root "Program Files\Microsoft Learning\20414\Drives\")` will create a valid syntax for path. That is, it will manage delimiters automatically.

`test-path` will return true if the path does exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a slightly different approach from what [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938816/1630171) suggested, because `Get-PSDrive` will enumerate more than just disk/network drives. Using WMI should provide slightly better performance:

```
$subfolder = "Program Files\Microsoft Learning\20414\Drives"

$drivesPath = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType=3 OR DriveType=4' | % {
  Join-Path $_.DeviceID $subfolder
} | ? { Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to get the drive of a mounted VHD:

```
Write-Output "Mount-VHD $targetVhdx..."
$mountVhd = Mount-VHD -Path $targetVhdx -Passthru

Write-Output "Select mounted DriveLetter..."
$mountDrive = $mountVhd | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemLabel -ne 'System Reserved'} | Select DriveLetter
```