# Only get the partition label

Tags: powershell

I'm coding a little script with Powershell.

The script is getting the drive letters and exports them with some additional code to the temp directory in a batch file.

Here's an example:

```
$TempFolderSavePath = $env:temp + "\SDelete.cmd"
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | Select-Object Name | foreach { $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {"SDelete -z "+ $_} | Out-File $TempFolderSavePath
```

The problem is, that the script is also including **mapped network drives**.

How I can only use the local drives?

Here's a version of the script without generating a new file and just outputting it to the console.

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | Select-Object Name | foreach { $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {"SDelete -z "+ $_} | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, `Get-PSDrive` doesn't know the difference betwee network and local drive. You can use `Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk`, which [supports filtering drives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17941801/503046) by type.

Filtering example:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | select-object DeviceID, DriveType, @{Name="Type";Expression={[IO.DriveType]$_.DriveType}} | ? {$_.Type -eq 'Fixed'}
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | ? {$_.DriveType -eq 3}
```

Comment: Here's the updated code:
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | select-object DeviceID, DriveType, @{Name="Type";Expression={[IO.DriveType]$_.DriveType}} | ? {$_.Type -eq 'Fixed'} | Select-Object DeviceID | foreach {$_.DeviceID}| ForEach-Object {"SDelete -z "+ $_} | Write-Host